# Is there any reward for collecting treasures?

Tags: uncharted-3

In the original Uncharted and in Uncharted 2 collecting treasures gave you points or money which you could spend on skins or unlocks to be used in subsequent playthroughs. Featurettes and art assets could also be purchased.

From what I can tell from the Uncharted 3 menus so far, the featurettes and art assets appear to be unlocked as you complete game levels, and there are no single-player unlocks at all.

So is there any reward for collecting treasures in Uncharted 3, besides the associated PS3 trophies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am quite far into the game and have not received any awards for the treasures I've collected. Also, a friend of mine has completed the game and gotten all the trophies, and treasures did go unrewarded.

**EDIT:** If it's worth anything, I beat the game yesterday and didn't get anything. I was a bit bummed when I found out there wouldn't be any cheats from collecting the treasures like in the second game.

Comment: I think its only to show off your e-peen and achievements, nothing else

Comment: Yeah I quite enjoyed going back and doing levels with unlimited grenades or rockets. I guess they saved all the unlocking for multiplayer.

Answer (score 0):

All you get are trophies. Bummer, because I loved the singleplayer store on U2